# Linux sandbox with C, secure?

Tags: linux, sandbox, secure-coding

I'm developing a generic honeypot for TCP services as part of my BA thesis.

I'm currently using Chroot, Linux Namespaces, Secure Computing and Capabilities to provide some sort of a Sandbox.

My question is: Are there any points I have to be aware of? Since I have to mount /proc in the sandbox, I'm curious if  it will affect the overall security of the host system.

(User namespaces are not an option btw.)

/* EDIT */
To be more clear: I'm using capabilities(7) and libseccomp to restrict the access to features such as syscalls for root and non-root users.

But what about files in /proc e.g. /proc/sys/* ? Should I blacklist files/directories with an empty bind-mount like firejail does?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer since it doesn't directly answer your question but isn't it more secure for you to run a whole VM or maybe just a container and a unikernel rather than just a chroot jail?

Comment: Since the honeypot is designed to work on small embedded systems e.g. OpenWrt, a VM is not an option.

Comment: Have a look at [systemd-nspawn](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-nspawn) for example, but I guess your sandbox is more advanced than that if you compare it against [firejail](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firejail). What about Chromium sandbox ?

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Yann Droneaud, reading the src of systemd-nspawn helped a lot.

I found the following /proc subdirs which should be bind mounted read-only/inaccessible:

```
/* Make these files inaccessible to container payloads: they potentially leak information about kernel
 * internals or the host's execution environment to the container */
            PROC_INACCESSIBLE("/proc/kallsyms"),
            PROC_INACCESSIBLE("/proc/kcore"),
            PROC_INACCESSIBLE("/proc/keys"),
            PROC_INACCESSIBLE("/proc/sysrq-trigger"),
            PROC_INACCESSIBLE("/proc/timer_list"),

/* Make these directories read-only to container payloads: they show hardware information, and in some
 * cases contain tunables the container really shouldn't have access to. */
            PROC_READ_ONLY("/proc/acpi"),
            PROC_READ_ONLY("/proc/apm"),
            PROC_READ_ONLY("/proc/asound"),
            PROC_READ_ONLY("/proc/bus"),
            PROC_READ_ONLY("/proc/fs"),
            PROC_READ_ONLY("/proc/irq"),
            PROC_READ_ONLY("/proc/scsi"),
```